# Could someone explain and help me understand how formatting of widgets works within Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, formatting, label, frames

I'm just messing about on Tkinter trying to create a basic name input system. I'm having a hard time grasping a few things:

- Why is it that regardless of where I attempt to grid a label, it always remains in the top left corner? How do I get it so I can 'freely position' the label around the window instead of it just remaining in this fixed position?
- I have a basic understanding of:

  ```
  root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

  root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
  ```

However, what do the different parameters mean and what does changing them actually do for the program.

- Is there a way to get text into the top center of the window and ensure it remains there, sort of like a title bit within the actual window. I understand this can be achieved using padding but padding doesn't allow the text to remain centered if the window size is changed

It would be a great help if someone could explain these, or even just one, to me. Thank you :)

```
    from tkinter import *

    fname = open("fname.txt", "a")


    root = Tk()
    root.title("First Name")
    root.geometry("500x300")

    main_frame = Frame(root, bg="#CECECE", width=490, height=245)

    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    main_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")

    firstName = Label(main_frame, text="First Name")
    firstName.grid(column=2, row=2)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a look at [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't use `.grid()`. Use `.place()` instead. You can place a widget almost anywhere on the screen with this geometry manager, and it has the added advantage of scaling down when the screen shrinks. For example:

```py
button1 = Button()
button1.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
```

This will put the button in the middle of the screen, no matter how much you shrink the screen.

Read more about [the place geometry manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

Hopefully this helps!

Also, pack and grid can't work together in the same master, because the program will try forever to find a solution that works for both geometry managers. Make sure that if you use grid, then stick with it.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's what I meant, when I said same window. I meant same master!

Comment: Personally I think the advice to use `place` is bad advice for a beginner. It often requires more work, and results in a less responsive UI.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think so too, but the OP doesn't say he is a begginer, so I thought I would post this.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that regardless of where I attempt to grid a label, it always remains in the top left corner?

It is because empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero.

> How do I get it so I can 'freely position' the label around the window instead of it just remaining in this fixed position?

TO "freely position" a widget you can use `place`. It excels at letting you place widgets exactly where you want. The downside is that you have to do all of the calculations, and take care of what happens when windows are resized, fonts are different, etc. `place` is good for absolute positioning (and even relative positioning) but it usually results in you having to do more work and ending up with a less responsive UI.

> I have a basic understanding of `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` ... However, what do the different parameters mean and what does changing them actually do for the program.

The first parameter is the row or column number that is to be configured. The `weight` parameter is a relative number that tells tkinter how to allocate extra space relative to other rows and columns. *If there is unallocated space*, it will be distributed among rows and columns with a non-zero weight.

For example, if one column has a weight of 2 and another has a weight of 1, the one with the weight of 2 will receive twice as much of the extra space. The same is true if the weights were 20 and 10 or 2000 and 1000.

> Is there a way to get text into the top center of the window and ensure it remains there?

There are several ways, but the answer for doing this with only one label in the whole window is going to be different with a label at the top and other things below. With grid, you have to consider the behavior of all rows and columns. Your question doesn't show a title so it's hard to give specific advice.

Comment: Thanks for this, really clears things up :). Just a question regarding my first question. How would I go about properly formatting a window using 'grid'. Say for example, I wanted to get a Label or entry in the centre of a window, but leave the rest of the window empty. How to I get it so that I can place a widget in the row or column I want. I understand empty rows and columns have size of zero now thank you for clearing that up, but is there any way for me to just get the widgets where I want them on the screen using grid? I am relatively new to tkinter -forgot to mention in my original post